# Повторно показываются вопросы в очереди проверки, отмеченные как пропущенные

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, очередь-проверок

Заметил, что для ряда вопросов как-то странно работает кнопка "Пропустить".
Похоже, что на следующие сутки часть помеченных вопросов снова возвращается в мою очередь проверки.

Пример такого вопроса: [**Умножение в php**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189569/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-php)

Данный вопрос я совершенно точно несколько раз отмечал как пропущенный, а он всплывает в очереди проверки уже второй или третий раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот проверка этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4995

[В логах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?page=8&userid=13336&skipped=true) есть ровно один раз, когда вы его пропустили:

```
VenZell     Умножение в php [закрыто]   Пропустить  16 апр '15 в 7:53
```

Возможно, в остальные разы вы просто закрывали страницу. (Либо в логировании ошибка)

Comment: последнюю строчку не понял. Я и так пишу, что пришлось несколько раз пропустить вопрос. Вопрос был дан как пример, но на тот момент он был такой не один. В любом случае, в последнее время я не замечал такого же поведения. Сейчас думаю, что возможно вопросы попадали и под автоматическую и под ручную тревогу. Может, дело в этом.

Comment: @VenZell: я имел в виду «закрывали»

Comment: нет, это исключено. Еще одно предположение в комментарии чуть выше

Comment: @VenZell: понял. Ну, воспроизвести теперь вряд ли получится. Может быть в логе остается запись об одном, последнем пропуске.